# Netlogo how turtles move others objects

Tags: netlogo

I have two kind of turtles :

- car
- object

The objective is that the car should find and grasp 3 objects and move them to the center. I tried to make link between turtle and object but I guess is a wrong idea.

My code so far:

```
to move-turtles
  ask car [
    right random 360
    forward 1
    ask other object-here [
      set color red
      create-links-to car 
      ]
  ]
end
```

I'm struggling with how the car can grasp and move objects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming or technology

Comment: @Kane I have cleaned up the code formatting. This is fairly clearly on topic.

Comment: @Kane no idea why you would even say that

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `tie` attribute of a link to make them move together. I have also done some code cleaning - if cars and objects are different breeds with singular car and object respectively, you don't need `other`, but you do need objects rather than object or you will get a syntax error (`<breeds>-here`).

In theory, the following code will randomly pick a car, move it one patch, create links with the objects there, then move 5 with those objects. However, it is not tested.

```
to move-turtles
  ask one-of cars [
    let thiscar self
    right random 360
    forward 1
    ask objects-here [
      set color red
      create-links-from thiscar [tie] 
    ]
  ]
  fd 5
end
```

Fixed to take into account the errors spotted by Seth!

Comment: i have this error : There is no agent for MYSELF to refer to

Comment: change `myself` to `self`

Comment: I think you probably also need to change `create-links-to` to `create-links-from`. To use `tie` correctly, the link must go from the controlling agent to the agent being controlled.

Comment: any idea how to remove link and push the object in another place, i try this ask thiscar [ask my-in-links [die]] but not working thanks for your help

Comment: Ask a new question when you have a new problem. Also, you need to explain much better than 'not working'. Is it generating an error? What behaviour is it doing and what did you actually want it to do?